# Hibernate NoClassDefFoundError org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration in Java web application

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I' m developing a simple JSF application which uses Hibernate. I imported all required libraries to WEB-INF/lib folder and also point them in classpath. But when I tried to compile it I got error:

[image]

Here is code where I create SessionFactory and use it:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
{
  try
  {
  Configuration configuration = new Configuration();//This line
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new   ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry(   );        
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
         }
       catch (Exception e)
{
throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
  }
  }
 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
 {
return buildSessionFactory();
 }
```

And here I use it:

```
 public static void  saveUser( String title)
     {
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();  
         Client client = new Client();
         ......
```

So what am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: What server are you using? It sounds like you need jta.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.transaction.SystemException` is in the `jta-x.y.jar` (x.y is the required version for the version of Hibernate you use). It should be in your classpath.

Hibernate requires a lot of libraries. To manage the dependencies, you should use something like Maven or Ivy.